# why does it keep saying "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

[this is the full error of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7H7l.png)

i would really love the help

```
mainshop = [{"name":"Time_watch","price":1000,"description":"Resets certain cooldowns (limited uses)(WIP)"}, {"name":"Gun","price":10000,"description":"A better way to rob people with a shorter cooldown!"}, {"name":"Guhhh Placeholder!!","price":10000000,"description":"I sure love placeholders"}]
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def shop(ctx):#real#:troll:.name
    em = discord.Embed(title = "Shopping District")

    for item in mainshop:
      name = item["name"]
      price = item["price"]
      desc = item["description"] #i do believe its because you have like no DESCRIPTION in the item list thing
      #get fake
      em.add_field(name = name, value = f"${price} | {desc}")
#real
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os
import json
 
##### START LEVEL COMMAND #####


@client.command(name='bal')
async def balance(ctx, user:discord.Member=None):
    colour = randint(0, 0xffffff)
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{user}'s balance", color=colour)
    em.add_field(name="Wallet", value=wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name="Bank", value=bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

async def buy_this(user,item_name,amount):
    item_name = item_name.lower()
    name_ = None
    for item in mainshop:
        name = item["name"].lower()
        if name == item_name:
            name_ = name
            price = item["price"]
            break

    if name_ == None:
        return [False,1]

    cost = price*amount

    users = await get_bank_data()

    bal = await update_bank(user)#r.i.p. KB's confindince

    if bal[0]<= cost:
        return [False,2]


    try:
        index = 0
        t = None
        for thing in users[str(user.id)]["bag"]:
            n = thing["item"]
            if n == item_name:
                old_amt = thing["amount"]
                new_amt = old_amt + amount
                users[str(user.id)]["bag"][index]["amount"] = new_amt
                t = 1
                break
            index+=1 
        if t == None:
            obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
            users[str(user.id)]["bag"].append(obj)
    except:
        obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
        users[str(user.id)]["bag"] = [obj]        

    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    await update_bank(user,cost*-1,"wallet")

    return [True,"Worked"]

@client.command()
async def buy(ctx,item,amount):#how come these arent definded no more? oh I prollydid smth by mistake guhhhhhhh
        res = await buy_this(ctx.author,item,amount) 

        if not res[0]:
         if res[1]==1:
            await ctx.send("That is not an item in shop")
            return
         if res[1]==2:
            await ctx.send(f"You don't have enough money to buy the {amount}")
            return
            await ctx.send(f"Successfully bought {amount}: {item}")



@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def bag(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    try: 
        bag = users[str(user.id)]["bag"]
    except: 
        bag = []


    em = discord.Embed(title = "Bag")
    for item in bag: 
        name = item["item"]
        amount = item["amount"]

        em.add_field(name = name, value = amount)

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
 #Oh you mean this ? oh yeah Idk what I put that there



async def open_account(user):
  
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
      
    return True




async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users



async def update_bank(user, change=0, mode="wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"], users[str(user.id)]["bank"]]
    return bal
```

the code that should matter. I do not understand at all what is wrong with the code. I used this code before no errors. So if anyone could please explain that would be greatly appreciated. I have tried putting this in its own thing. it didnt work still. i have also tried putting if bal <= int(cost) this also didnt work.

Comment: Whatever your second argument is, it is a string.  You need to convert it using int() or float() before you do the comparison so they are compatible types.

Comment: Did you try to print `bal` and `cost`?

Comment: What do you get when you `print(repr(bal[0]))` and `print(repr(cost))`?

Answer (score 0):

on the line `if bal[0]<= cost:` if you cast to an integer `int(bal[0])` it should be comparing two integers then, and vice-versa if cost is a string

Comment: this did not work sorry

Answer (score 0):

Cost is already an int, looks like bal[0] is a string. Try `int(bal[0]) <= cost` instead (or `float(bal[0])` if it has decimals)

Comment: did not work.. sorry.

Comment: Either `bal[0]` is a string, or `cost` is a string. The error wont throw otherwise. Ensuring both are integers will not give this problem

Comment: @AnthonyL i have tried putting them like that before. didnt work. if i put int(cost) then it just gives no error but says you cant afford the item even if you have enough in your bal.

Comment: @KB256 So both answers here solve the problem you had? Post again with a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) and I bet you will already know the answer

Comment: @KB256 It's written in your post that int(cost) doesn't work, now you say it doesn't throw an error when you do that.... If you don't provide the appropriate information it'll be hard to help you. Also, if the code is no longer raising a comparison error then the topic of this question is solved and you're having a separate issue which likely needs a different question with more info provided.